Poor Performance when display a degenerate dimension next to other dimension
I have a table with "Open Order" records which stores the orders still under delivery and also containing customer IDs and Product IDs for that Order. for Customer and product IDs I already created two dimensions for them and link them with the fact table per IDs. but for other attributes like PO#, Customer PO#, delivery status, delivery date and Customer Comments that couldn't be in one standalone dimension, I had to create a degenerate dimension.
so, When I display Open Order fact measures against Customer and product dimensions the performance is working fine.
When I display Open Order fact measures against Customer and product dimensions the performance is working fine.
but once I combine Customer, Product and the degenerate dimension attributes together, the performance is so bad and it takes 15 min.
How to solve this performance issue.

Please update your question with the full DDL for your tables (including any indexes) and the EXPLAIN PLANs for both queries, all as editable text
